# Erroneous parenthesis error in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, fortran77, fortran95

Erroneous parenthesis error in fortran in following lines (lines not necessarily in same sequence in program).

P. S, - I am using force compiler

```
QWE(8)=(1.+5.*HILF+RWS(6)*(2*((RWS(6)**2-1)/(HILF1)-RWS(6)-HILF1)

IF (ZWEIP .EQ. 2) S(47)=0.25+(HILF)/300

IF (ZWEIP .EQ. 4) S(47)=0.2 +(HILF)/500.

S(47)=0.2 +(HILF)/800.

D(51) =(DR(7,8))**2*SP(2,8)*L(26)*1.0E-3
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first line, there's an obvious parenthesis mismatch:

```
QWE(8)=(1.+5.*HILF+RWS(6)*(2*((RWS(6)**2-1)/(HILF1)-RWS(6)-HILF1)
   1 0 1              2 1 2  34   5 4     3 4     3    4 3      2
```

But apart from that, I don't understand what your question is. What is your error message?